# Custom error pages in Rails not showing pretty 404 for expired assets (that no longer exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm showing pretty error pages ([example)](http://note.io/Xpqnyw) to my users when a i.e. an error 500 or 404 occurs. I've followed [this guide](http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages#comment-802263873), and it works great for pages that no longer existbut not for expired assets (that no longer exist), i.e. images such as /assets/wood_bg2-7ab28512ecf6eeeb5f3742babca48a7b5.png - for those, an "empty" and "ugly" missing image is shown ([example](http://note.io/YgAK6b)) rather than my nice custom 404 error page.

The error I get through my exception_notification gem:

```
An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in errors#error_404: Missing template errors/error_404, application/error_404 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:png], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

So maybe I just need to "tell" the error page/routes that it should show my error page for png, jpg, etc files also?

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once implemented the nifty_errorpages gem. It is  available on github: https://github.com/mattherick/nifty_errorpages. Maybe my implementation could help you to fix your problem. It is for rails 3.2. If you have 3.1 simple check out the source code, otherwise you could add it to your Gemfile and try it out directly.